# Asymptotic evaluation of an integral using steepest descent

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am trying to evaluate this integral
$$\int_0^\pi{te^{ix\cos(t)}dt},\ x\to\infty$$
I am asked to use the method of steepest descent to get the asymptotic up to the $x^{-3}$ term.

I get stuck quite at the beginning as i try to find the contour along which i should integrate.
I also considered using the stationary phase method but i'm not sure how to get the approximation up to the asked order.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Draw the region $\operatorname {Re}(i \cos t) < 0$. From that, determine how a suitable contour should look globally and what the steepest descent directions at the saddle points are. A change of variables brings the exponential part into the form $e^{x (u_0 - u^2)}$ near a saddle point. Then you can expand the non-exponential part and integrate termwise. That will require some calculations, as you need the expansions up to the fifth order.